# Normalization/Normalisation Normalization/Normalisation

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Can we make stackoverflow.com [normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalisation) a synonym for [normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization)? These are just variant spellings of the same word & notion.

Can we retag the [normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalisation) questions?

[normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalisation) has 23 questions, [normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization) 2.3K.

From https://stackoverflow.com/tags/normalization/synonyms:

> Incorrectly tagged questions are hard to find and answer. If you know of common, alternate spellings or phrasings for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.

Alternatively, maybe eventually 4 more people will discover they both exist and vote it a synonym. Meanwhile (a few) questions of interest will be missed. Also, then the ratio might not be as nice. Also a pun.

(Normalization/normalisation is a mathematical notion; database normalization & others are specific cases. A question about the applicaton of a notion to writing a program is on-topic, and many notions are common & specific enough to tag; otherwise there would be no non-language tags.)

Comment: How about if we just remove all those? They are as useful as writing, reading, moving, etc...

Comment: And none of those you can specialize in. Look, topics represented by tags should ideally cover a book or an entire chapter. database-normalization can be very difficult, with all debt, and mathematical notions aren't even on topic on a programming site.

Comment: @Braiam i wish i could downvote your comment to infinity.  I don't see an issue with the tag in question, assuming we can address the american vs British spelling issue.  Seems like a perfectly valid tag one we have a single option  and not multiple options with variously spelled variants

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories." How many mathematicians experts you expect to find in a site dedicated to professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it? I'm economist, and there's no tag I would remove faster than the ones about economic concepts.

Comment: @Braiam Your quote supports my post & comments. I don't see how the part of your comment after the quote  is relevant to my post or the quote. Also it misinterprets "mathematical" as "not practical". Programmers with a computer science or software engineering background are unlikely to think that arbitrary programming does not involve "mathematical notions". Also please see the quote re tag synonyms now in my question.

Comment: @Braiam The "tag/expert" argument is not a valid argument as per the [official burnination guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288751). You're reading very far into a very specific portion of one sentence in the help text. Directly prior to that sentence is another sentence: _"A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question."_. Directly after that sentence is another sentence: _"Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you."_. Tags are not **just** _"a means of connecting experts with questions"_.

Comment: @Braiam Also, you do not _have_ to be a mathematics expert to answer a programming question about normalization.

Comment: @TinyGiant It's on the very *tag creation guidelines*, which are way above that one. Shog mainly made that guideline to prevent folks from wasting time on stuff it wasn't urgent, not to prohibit them from gravitating towards the ideal. Why nobody has ever tried to present post that are both on topic and no other tag applies? Like, I don't know... database design?

Comment: Why everyone uses rhetoric and dogma instead of bringing facts *and* numbers. I've checked the freaking questions before, math is on the *very* low side of the pool of questions, most of them are about normalizing some data, which, again, depends on the software where that data is stored.

Comment: @Braiam Re "tag creation guidance": It's not. The tag creation guidelines say nothing to the effect that you would have us believe. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags says nothing about tag experts. Neither does https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-add-tags, or any of the other tag related pages I've found in the help center. In fact, "tag" and "expert" are only in the same help center article once (https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), and there is only one occurrence of "expert" in that article.

Comment: The usefulness of this tag is about 0. There are better tags out there that has several times more followers and answerers that this one and almost all questions. Heck, I've seen tags with more followers/questions which are smaller than this one!

Comment: @Braiam You seem to have tunnel vision re "math". It is irrelevant what adjectives are applicable to a topic if it is useful, and useful is subjective & empirical. If you want to burninate these tags, which indeed have entire books and chapters published re special cases in a programming context, please post a question requesting & justfying. My question is about two spellings for one topic. If you want vote on that, do that too.

Comment: @TinyGiant "Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a **new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site**." How the heck you miss that line?

Comment: @Braiam What does that have to do with experts? It just means that you should make sure your tag isn't covered by an existing tag to prevent duplication. It's your opinion that the tag is not useful, but according to the official burnination guidelines, I see no reason to burninate this tag. You have yet to make a valid argument against this tag.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't have the word, doesn't mean that it isn't still within the context, @Tiny. One needs to actually read and comprehend the nuances of the *entire text*. I cherry pick lines because that's what is nearest to which I want to convey, but the entire page keeps talking about the expert, even if it doesn't mentions it.

Comment: @Braiam That sentence has nothing at all to do with the quantity of experts available to answer questions on a given topic. The only thing that sentence has anything to do with is the duplication of tags. That is to prevent synonyms and duplicates (***like the situation we are in right now with normalization and normalisation***).